# Javascript, cant subtract values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Hi guys so basically i am trying to add data in a nutrtion label which i built. So the label it self has everything from fat, carbs , protein etc. Now i have set up a database with:

```
ingName: ....
fat: ... 
carbs ... etc
```

So right now i am just trying to get it to work for fat. Once i do this i can easily do the others. I can search through the database easily.When the user presses Add button it will add the ingredient below the search box and then change the content of fat. However i am having a major problems with it right now.

When the user clicks on the red cross to delete the element i want it to subtract the fat of the label. So if the user adds an apple with 1 fat and then adds banana with 4 fat. Then the user decides to delete the apple it should go back to 4 fat from 5 fat.

Comment: "...it should go back to 4 fat from 5 fat" - where does it go back to exactly? Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: @rby its just simple math, so i can add the fat content fine, but i cant take away , you see this example ; https://juicerecipes.com/build/ how you can add something and then if you are not happy you click the cross and get rid of it?

Comment: It is something to do with my last function: $('.selectedStuff span').on("click", function(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be storing the new fat counter in each new span, so if you add apples worth 5 then you make a span with data of 5, then you add that to your `current_fat` counter and the next time you add another item the data of that item is now accumulative. I have created some of the code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/z4rx21fg/). It seems to be working the way you describe now.

I know what I am saying may be confusing, so look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/z4rx21fg/).

- If you add apples worth 5
- Then add bananas worth 5
- Then add green beans worth 5

You are taking the 5 from the apples and putting those 5 points into this variable called `current_fat` then you add the point value for the bananas and then the point value for the green beans so what you end up with is a span with apples at 5, bananas at 10, and green beans at 15, so when you remove green beans all of your fat is dropping to zero, instead you need to take each item with it's own point value into the span.

```
var current_fat = 0;

$('#addButton').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($('#search_term').val() == '') {
    alert('please fill something in text box');
  } else {
    var searchedValue = $('#search_term').val();
    temp = $("#fat").text();
    temp = parseInt(temp);

    temp = $("#fat").text();
    temp = parseInt(temp);

    current_fat += temp;

    $("#fat").text(current_fat);
    var divHolder = $('.selectedStuff');
    $("<div>" + searchedValue + "<span data-fat='" + temp + "'>X</span></div>").css({
      'background-color': 'yellow',
      'width': '700px',
      'margin-top': '10px',
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-color': '#0000ff'
    }).appendTo(divHolder);
  }


  $('.selectedStuff span').on("click", function() {
    var fat = Number($(this).data('fat'));
    alert(fat);
    $('#fat').text(Number($('#fat').text()) - fat);
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: hmm its actually working but taking away the wrong amounts now

Comment: i am not sure i can , i have php , as its all linked to my database etc

Comment: or i am not sure whatever is easier for u

Comment: @Nevershow2016 You couldn't modify the fiddle with some mock data to show a demo of what is going wrong now? If not I can try to help via screen shots in chat but my php skills are not awesome.

Comment: I think chat would be easier, i think it is something to do with the js

Comment: The last function is making eveyrthing go mental

Comment: so i think if i can get the correct algorithm i can get it to work

Comment: you are right those, when i add 3 apples which have 1g of fat, and i take away the thrid one it will actually take off 3g of fat rather than 1g of fat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106959/discussion-between-nevershow2016-and-noctane).

Comment: Ah i been in this room , how do i join urs?

Answer (score -1):

You can subtract and show the values by introducing one temp variable. Please find  working example.

```js
var current_fat = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {
            if(event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46) {
                var search_term = $("#search_term").val();
                if(search_term != '') {
                    $.get( 'build.php', { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) {
                    $('.result').html( data );    
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $('.result').on('click', 'li', function( event ) {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#search_term').val(result_value);
            $('.result').html('');
        });

        $('#addButton').on('click', function( event ) {
            if($('#search_term').val() ==''){
                alert('please fill something in text box'); 
            }else{ 
                    var searchedValue = $('#search_term').val(); 
                    temp = $("#fat").text(); 
                    temp = parseInt(temp);
                   $.post( 'build.php', { 'search_term':searchedValue, 'current_fat':temp }, function(data) { 
       
                       $('.result').html( data ); 
                   
       }); 
                 temp = $("#fat").val(); 
        temp = parseInt(temp); 
     current_fat += temp; 
     $("#fat").val(current_fat);
                
    var divHolder = $('.selectedStuff');
     $("<div>" + searchedValue + "<span data-fat='"+current_fat+"' data-itemfat='"+temp+"'>X</span></div>").css({
        'background-color': 'yellow',
        'width': '700px',
        'margin-top': '10px',
        'border-style': 'solid',
        'border-color': '#0000ff'
       }).appendTo(divHolder);
    }

   $('.selectedStuff span').on("click", function(){
    var totalfat = Number($(this).data('fat')); 
    var fat = Number($(this).data('itemfat')); 
    $('#fat').val(totalfat-fat);
    $(this).parent().remove();  
   });
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div> Search Term :&nbsp;<input type="text" id="search_term" />&nbsp; FAT: &nbsp;<input type="text" id="fat" /> <input type="button"  id="addButton" value="add" /></div>
<div class="selectedStuff"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i have copied the js file exact, it adds fine, but does not subtract at all :(

Comment: i am not so sure why

Comment: I am not sure could it be my php file which is making it go haywire?

Comment: <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Total Fat</b>
         <span id="fat">0.0</span>
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>22%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>

Comment: That is my fat html bit were its stored

Comment: I have posted my php above